# Redux - Having an issue concatenating new state when an Item is added to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, react-redux, reducers

Currently having an issue with my reducer function where it will not update the `questionList.items` array. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here so it would be awesome if someone could point me in the right direction :)

Below is the snippet of code I'm having an issue with. My problem lies with my `ADD_QUESTIONS` action as **it does not concatenate existing items in the array with the new item**. Instead, **it overwrites the existing item in the array**.

```
const ADD_QUESTION = 'ADD_QUESTION';
const FETCH_QUESTIONS = 'FETCH_QUESTIONS';
const FETCH_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS';
const FETCH_QUESTIONS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_QUESTIONS_FAILURE';

const INITIAL_STATE = { 
  questionsList: {items: [{
    id: 2222,
    questionString: 'your name',
    rejected: true
  }], error:null, loading: false},
    newQuestion:{question:null, error: null, loading: false}, 
    activeQuestion:{question:null, error:null, loading: false}, 
    deletedQuestion: {question: null, error:null, loading: false},
};

const questionsReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const { payload, type } = action;
  switch (type) {
  case FETCH_QUESTIONS:
      return { ...state, questionsList: {items:[], error: null, loading: true} }; 
    case FETCH_QUESTIONS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, questionsList: {items: action.payload, error:null, loading: false} };
    case ADD_QUESTION:
      /** PROBLEM LIES HERE */ 
      return { ...state, questionsList: { items: [...state, payload], error: null, loading: false } }
    default: return state
  }
}

export default questionsReducer;
```

I've taken a screenshot of my redux devtools console to hopefully better show the issue i'm dealing with. By taking a look at the picture below you will see that the initial item in the `items` array gets replaced when `ADD_QUESTION` fires.

[image: Screen Shot 2017-03-28 at 10.58.08 AM.png]

Comment: It seems suspicious that you have `...state` twice on that line.

Comment: You should split your reducer into smaller ones and use composeReducers function. This will let you control your state in more granular way and will save you using spread operator everytime

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to spread your whole `state`, not only the list of questions:

```
return { ...state, questionsList: { items: [...state, payload], error: null, loading: false } }
```

You cannot spread an object into an array. Instead, **only spread the relevant slice of the state**:

```
return { ...state, questionsList: { items: [...state.questionsList.items, payload], error: null, loading: false } }
```

Comment: that worked perfect.. thanks so much :) i didn't realize that the spread operator was able to be used like that because I could've sworn my build system shot out an error. nonetheless it's all ready to go now. thanks again for the help and that insight. it's definitely going to come in handy.